# Angular 2 - how to share component data with transcluded template

Tags: angular, transclusion

I'm new to Angular2. I'm trying to do the following:

I want a wrapper component to read a filter attribute and use it to retrieve data from a data source; then make this data available to the portion of template that is **transcluded** inside it, without prior knowledge of what components it will transclude.

For example, and just to give an idea:

```html
<wrapper-component filter="key='abcd'">

    <item-viewer *ngFor="let item of retrievedData"></item-viewer>

</wrapper-component>
```

Where there are a whole set of different item-viewer components that can be nested inside the wrapper component.

Is there any way in Angular2 to do this? Or maybe the approach is completely wrong?

Comment: What don't you pass it to `<wrapper-...>` **and** `<item-viewer>`. You can use a shared service to share data, otherwise there is no easy way for transcluded elements - except you know the type of the component in advance.

Comment: hi @GünterZöchbauer , thanks for your comment. I've found a solution to my question and posted it as an answer- I see you're an expert in Angular2, maybe you can tell me if you see issues with the approach. Thanks!

Comment: Looks fine. .  . . ..   . . ..

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after two days of confusion I managed to get what I wanted- it's not optimal but it works, and it looks simple. The whole trick was to add a template variable to reference the wrapper component.

The template becomes:

```html
<wrapper-component #mySource filter="key='abcd'">

    <item-viewer *ngFor="let item of mySource.itemlist" [data]="item"></item-viewer>

</wrapper-component>
```

Once the wrapper component has been assigned to the #mySource template variable, it is possible to reference it and its public properties in the transcluded template.

Then, whenever there is a change in WrapperComponent.itemlist the ngFor output is updated accordingly.

This is my totally generic item visualisation component:

```typescript
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'item-viewer',
    templateUrl: '<h1>{{data.title}</h1><p>{{data.paragraph}}</p>'
})
export class ItemViewer{
    @Input() data: any;

    constructor() { }
}
```

And this is the wrapper component:

```typescript
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'wrapper-component',
    template: '... <ng-content></ng-content> ...'
})
export class WrapperComponent{
    @Input() filter: string;
    itemlist: any[];

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        // every three seconds the component adds a new item to
        // itemlist to show that it is rendered by ItemViewer
        setInterval(()=> {
            this.itemlist.push({ title: "title"+filter, 
                                 paragraph: "par"+ filter
                               });
            }, 3000);
    }
}
```

The only major fault I can find with this solution is that the #mySource variable becomes a global template variable- it can be referenced also outside the transclusion, which is definitely undesirable. And if you want to reuse the same method multiple times, you need to change the variable name every time.

If you have better ideas or issues to point out, please let me know.